# state is not updated in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, code-editor

I'm making code editor, default language code should change, when user change language from dropdown options.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwvM9.png)

setCode state is not at all updated on the screen, but when I checked logs it was showing code of previous state.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih6OB.png)

Comment: Of course, you won't see the updated `code` just after running `setCode` because the state update is reflected on the next render. You should understand why the state management in React works like this, instead of seeing this as some trouble.

Comment: @AkshitMehra so what changes should I do, how can I change state before next render happen

Answer (score 0):

**Why React does not immediately update state**
The state update is queued for the next render. This is done to avoid multiple re-renders on every state change if you have multiple states in your component. Once all the states are updated the re-render will follow.

**But what if you want to perform some operation on the value before the next re-render **
You can force a state update by passing a function to setState. So instead of this:

```
setLanguage(s1)
```

Try this:

```
setLanguage(l => l = s1)
```

You can read more in the official React docs [here](https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates)

**Edit**: setState is asynchronous meaning setLanguage() is put in a queue which is executed AFTER it is done with everything else. You are console logging the value of s1 which is correctly received. Try console logging language and you'll see that it's still not updated. Try the solution above to force state update.

Comment: Thanks, but my main concern is state value is not reflecting on the screen its showing initial value of state, but on log, value of state(code) is changed. renders. I have added Image of the output above.